# setInterval odd (buggy?) behavior within a $(document).ready(function() { ... }); block

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me start here. At w3cshools.com - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp - they have a snippet demo-ing how to use javascript setInterval function (surprisingly it has a mismatched </form> but thats beside the point).

I needed to use setInterval() and at times I like referring to some "standard" body to take a glimpse of the recommended usage. In my development environment, something seems to be mangling setInterval() behavior/working when I use it within a jquery **$(document).ready(function() { ... });** block.

**Illustration 1 - WORKS:** Typical/Traditional <script> block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var refreshIntervalId;

    function testMessage() {
        window.alert("Hello");
    }
    refreshIntervalId = setInterval("testMessage()", 5000);
</script>
```

**Illustration 2 - DOES NOT WORK:** jQuery block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var refreshIntervalId;

        function testMessage() {
            window.alert("Hello");
        }
        refreshIntervalId = setInterval("testMessage()", 5000);
    });
</script>
```

**Illustration 3 - WORKS:**
jQuery block - using setInterval(testMessage, 5000) instead of setInterval("testMessage()", 5000)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var refreshIntervalId;

        function testMessage() {
            window.alert("Hello");
        }
        refreshIntervalId = setInterval(testMessage, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

It turns out that if I try to pass the function as a string from with the **$(document).ready(function() {});** block, I get an error indicating that the function is not defined. Just so we dont get side-tracked IE, Chrome, and Firefox all report errors:

**IE**: Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property 'testMessage' is null or undefined, not a Function object

**Chrome**: Uncaught ReferenceError: testMessage is not defined (anonymous function)

**Firefox**: testMessage is not defined.

What I would like to find out (if possible) is, could this be a result of standards non-conformance or what be going wrong when I try to use **setInterval("testMessage()", 5000)** from within the jQuery block? Could some mangling be happening or is this the right behavior?

Comment: "surprisingly it has a mismatched `</form>`"... http://w3fools.com/ (As for your actual problem, you should never pass a string to `setInterval`. Pass a reference to the function instead, which as you've said, works fine.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` break scope, so it can't find `testMessage` when it goes looking for it (because that function is scoped inside the anonymous function you pass to `ready`). Browsers are behaving correctly.

This is one of the reasons you should never, ever use the string format … or try to learn from the dreadful W3Schools.

Comment: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` break scope && (because that function is scoped inside the anonymous function you pass to `ready`) explains it. Moving the function to a more global scope will fix the problem but I think your advice about not using the string format is the safer alternative. Thanks

Comment: Indeed. Globals are bad! BAAAAD! :)

Comment: Now that we are there, is w3cschools.com that unreliable? Aren't they a part (or under) W3C Consortium?

Comment: @John Gathogo — Yes they are that bad, and no they aren't part of the W3C (but they get a lot of good will from people who think that sharing a couple of letters of the name is significant).

Comment: @JohnGathogo: Note that it's "w3schools", not "w3cschools", and it's not associated to W3C. Several examples on w3schools are outdated (like using strings in setInterval) or plainly wrong, but it's not quite as bad as the w3fools site makes it out to be. Generally it's not worse than any other random examples on the web, but it's not an authority for web standards.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that the browsers say that the function isn't defined, is that it's not defined in the scope where the interval runs. You have declared the function locally inside another function, so it doesn't exist in the global scope where the interval runs.

This is not due to jQuery, simply due to the anonymous function that you wrap the code in. This code shows the same error:

```
(function() {

  function testMessage() {
    window.alert("Hello");
  }

  var refreshIntervalId = window.setInterval("testMessage()", 5000);

})();
```

You can declare the function globally instead, then you can use a string for the interval:

```
function testMessage() {
  window.alert("Hello");
}

(function() {

  var refreshIntervalId = window.setInterval("testMessage()", 5000);

})();
```

Common practice is to use the function itself rather than a string in the interval call:

```
(function() {

  function testMessage() {
    window.alert("Hello");
  }

  var refreshIntervalId = window.setInterval(testMessage, 5000);

})();
```

If you need to pass a value to the function, you can use an anonymous function in the call:

```
(function() {

  function testMessage(msg) {
    window.alert(msg);
  }

  var refreshIntervalId = window.setInterval(function() { testMessage("Hello"); }, 5000);

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

function testMessage() and any other function must be declared OUTSIDE $(document).ready()

Comment: Only if you use the string format, but that is just using bad code style in order to compensate for using bad code style when using `setInterval` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

as @Quentin mentioned it's because the testMessage function is defined within the document ready and so outside the scope of the interval.

If you must define you're interval within the document ready you could do

```
refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
    window.alert("Hello");
}, 5000);
```